# copy specific line of ith file to another file as ith line

Tags: bash, copy, line

I am going to do sdv calculation.

I have lots of files. Each file has 2000 lines. I only need the last line (2000th) of each file, and I want to copy each of them into one file.

For example,

```
last line of first file will be the first line of new file
last line of second file will be the second line of new file.
.......
......
last line of nth file will be nth line of the new file.
```

I am thinking something like this:

```
case=$1 # total numer of files
for (( i = 1; i <= $case ; i ++ ))
do
    file=PPD$i           # files are numbered as PPD1, PPD2.....PPDi
    some command.....>final.dat
done
```

Comment: With `sed -n '2000p' file` you will print the 2000th line of `file`. Then you can redirect to `final.dat`. Is there any pattern on your files name?

Comment: If you are sure you want the last line (even if it isn't line 2000) you can use `tail -1 file`.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui.  The problem is that when I do the loop, the final.dat will be rewritten, so it only contains the 2000th of the last file....Sorry for stupid question, I'm new in Linux.....

Comment: No problem being new :)  Use `>` to _create_ a file and _fill_ it with the output (if it exists, it gets emptied first).  Use `>>` to _append_ the output to a file (if it doesn't exist, it gets created).

Comment: wow, it works. Thanks very much. Bash is so strong. I was wondering whether I have to do it by hand. Thanks all of you~~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
some command.....>final.dat
```

you can say:

```
sed '2000!d' $file >> final.dat
```

Be warned that the `sed` command would not produce any output if a file doesn't have 2000 lines.

Comment: Yes!, I have edited my question. I think it is helpful for people like me, who is new in Linux.

Comment: Thanks all of you~. This is a nice forum. I will be here since now to learn something from all of you guys~.

Comment: @user3065582 You don't need to edit your question to reflect the _answer_.  Consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it worked for you.  That would help someone looking for an answer.

Comment: oh, yes, sorry. new user. don't know the rule. do I need to change it back?

Comment: @user3065582 Don't bother.  I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 1):

If you're always looking for the last line, use the following:

```
some command | tail -n 1 > final.dat
```

if you have already files all files and they *contain a line break at the end*, you could make it even more easy by doing this

```
tail -n 2 -q /path/to/files/* > final.dat
```

-n 2 in this case to get the linebreak in your output